# Getting the issue to get specific timezone time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the issue to get difference between two times inn specific timezone. I am using the counter plugin in which I need to run the counter on specific time. I am using the following code.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="flipclock.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="flipclock.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
offset = -5.0
clientDate = new Date();
utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
var shour=serverDate.getHours();
var smin = serverDate.getMinutes();
//var stime=shour+':'+smin();
var date1 = new Date('3/09/2015 12:00:00 PM -5:00');

var stime = serverDate.getTime();
 alert(moment());
 var clock; 
 var date  = new Date('09/03/2015 12:00:00 -5:00');
 var now   = new Date();
 var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - stime;

  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
  clockFace: 'HourCounter',
  countdown: true
 });

    });
 </script>
 <body>
  <div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
 </body>
```

I am using the EST timezone. I need to run the counter up to 12 PM according to the EST. For this I am using the var date  = new Date('09/03/2015 12:00:00 -5:00'); but it is not working. Please let me know how I can fix it

Comment: you mean you want to the show the clock running for EST time??

Comment: want to change the 12PM time in EST

Comment: Without using some plugging try this demo to see if it works -- Its gets your Timezone offest  in hours and subtracts from UTC time offset then subtracts how many hours EST timezone is from UTC -- https://jsfiddle.net/o8k7oqxk/

Comment: If you want a more elaborate World clock then you can use this code i found on the net some years back.  You probably find the country you need to get the current time from -- https://jsfiddle.net/sfsmgqpr/